# Postgres asking for System Users password

Tags: postgresql

I have set up Postgres and want to use

`pg_dump -Fc mydb > dump.db`

to copy the content of my db into a file. pg_dump is asking e for the System Users password, which does not work. I have never asked Postgres to use my system user as the default user. I'd be incredibly happy with the default user:postgres password:postgres, but Postgresql is making things hard for me.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I do not need the system user in my pg database

Comment: then add the user name you want to use to the command: `pg_dump -U postgres ...`

Comment: @JGH Thanks! The flag actually works. but im running into this issue many times and would like to solve it without having to manually specify the user each time

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the "defaults" by setting environment variables.  PGUSER, PGPASSWORD.  Be aware though that it may be possible for other users of the system to see your PGPASSWORD setting, so for that a .pgpass file would generally be preferred.

Comment: can i get rid of the default system user by using .pgpass?